# How can I acquire more Amritas?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

I'm fighting the ant queen on level 12 but keep running low on TP in the last half of the fight. This slows my DPS down too much and I end up losing the war of attrition. The shop isn't selling any amritas, and the one TP item they do sell only restores 10 TP.

Is there something I can farm and sell to the shop so that they'll put some amritas up for sale?

Comment: Just to head off folks who suggest things like bards to handle the TP issues, this is Story Mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need Lapis Strawberry from the 3rd Stratum Take Points ([click here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/709464-etrian-odyssey-untold-the-millennium-girl/faqs/68469?page=8#section418), Ctrl + F and enter the item name)

As you will see, it's a rare find and i think at this point i had Take skills of 10 and still didn't get too many, there are 2 Take points on Floor B12 so you can run around going to these and waiting for them to replenish is a good way to grind EXP (level 12 seems a bit low to me, i average 2 levels per mapped floor).

Also i'd invest in *Focus*, for every Level in this skill will allow the user (Arthur and Simon) will recover 1 TP only if they are at full health, since i normally have Simon in the front line this means Arthur could have Infinite TP with the basic Formulas, at a high enough level your TP Gain will be greater than your spend (at least for weaker Formulas).

I also remember Rosa having a cordial that's like her initial one but regens TP instead of HP but i always use the initial one or the one that up's health in rare cases.

Finally, i'd rush the queen, this way not as many eggs have been laid and since the Ant Queen and her spawn are weak to Ice, Ricky and Arthur can double up the damage for a turn or 2

Answer (score 1):

You actually can change classes if a character is above level 30, but that's besides the point. You can sell Strawberries from Stratum 2 Take points to unlock Amrita II (May have changed to a weaker Amrita in EO:U). Try to get some conditional drops from monsters and FOEs, too. The weapons and armor you get from those will skyrocket your DPS. Using an analysis lens will reveal all drops, so use the name of the drop to figure out the condition for the drop i.e. Bound Scythe from Deathstalkers requires killing it when it's arms are bound. If all else fails, just turn down the difficulty, fight the boss, then crank it back up. You can only change the difficulty while in town though, so be careful.